# Runtime meta programming in ceylon

Tags: metaprogramming, ceylon

I get unexpected results from the following code snippet using the eclipse ide:

```
class Example(String s = "init") {
    shared String a() => "Func 1";
    shared String b = "Attr 1";
    shared String c(Integer i) { return "Func 2"; }
}


shared
void run() {    

  // 1.
  print("getAttributes: " + `Example`.getAttributes().string);
  print("getMethods:    " + `Example`.getMethods().string);
  // prints:   []  
  // i.e. doesnt print any attribute or method

  // 2.
  value e = Example()
  type(e);  // error
  e.type(); // error, should be replaced by the ide with the above version.

}
```

ad 1.) I get as a result:

```
getAttributes: []
getMethods:    []
```

where I expected lists containing attributes or methods.

ad 2.) The doc says:

"The type() function will return the closed type of the given instance, which can only be a ClassModel since only classes can be instantiated.
..."

But I cant find the type() function and others related to meta programming, i.e. I dont get a tooltip, but instead I get a runtime (!) error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.redhat.ceylon.compiler.java.language.UnresolvedCompilationError: method or attribute does not exist: 'type' in type 'Example'
```

So, where is the equivalent to the backticks `Example`.... as a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `` `Example`.getAttributes() `` returns an empty list because `getAttributes` takes three type arguments: `Container`, `Get`, `Set`. When called as `getAttributes()`, the typechecker tries to infer them, but since there’s no information (no arguments with the appropriate type), the inferred type argument is `Nothing`. Since `Nothing` is not a container of any of the class’ members, the resulting list is empty. Use `getAttributes<>()` instead to use the default type arguments, or specify them explicitly (e. g. `getAttributes<Example>()`). Same thing with `getMethods()`. [Try online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=150a0c4183c4bdb0a1d7acd6118e0632)
2. The `type` function is in `ceylon.language.meta` and needs to be imported: `import ceylon.language.meta { type }`. Once you do that (and remove the `e.type()` line), the compilation error will go away.
3. If you directly want a meta object of the function, you can write `` `Example.a` ``.

Comment: So, this should give me a list of attributes: value  ga = `Example`.getAttributes<Example, String, String>;
 print("getAttributes: " + ga.string); but it prints:  getAttributes: Attribute<Example,String,String>[](Type<Annotation>*), which is nice but not a list of attributes. I think I gave enough information to get a list of attributes ... Why is it necessary to specify additional information and what additional information does this function expect in order to give me a list of attributes; it asks for: Type<Annotation>* ?

Comment: That's a function reference. You're missing the the parentheses to invoke it. Try `getAttributes<Example, String, String>()`.